# Read arguments in Gerrit hook script

Tags: bash, hook, gerrit

I have created `comment-added` Gerrit (v. 2.8) hook:

```
PROJECT="UNKNOWN"
AUTHOR="UNKNOWN"

while [[ $# > 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
shift

case $key in
    --project)
        PROJECT="$1"
        shift
    ;;
    --author)
        AUTHOR="$1"
        shift
    ;;
    *)
        # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done

# do something with the $PROJECT variable
```

The arguemts reading idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203146/878514). According to the [documentation](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-hooks.html#_comment_added) this hook should be invoked with both `project` and `author` arguments. If I simulate invoke with the following command, everything works fine:

```
./commend-added --branch test --project testproject --author testauthor --whatever sth
```

However, when the hook is executed from Gerrit, both `PROJECT` and `AUTHOR` variables have default `UNKNOWN` value. Why?

I have inspected that the `$#` variable has value of `16` when called from Gerrit. I have also verified that the `while` loop never gets executed when the script is called from Gerrit.

I have also tried another loop with `$#` variable and it is neither executed:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    # do something
done
```

However, I'm able to iterate over `$@` variable. By using it, I also verified that the arguments supplied to the script by Gerrit are the same as in docs.

What am I doing wrong? How to read arguments when the hook is executed by Gerrit?

Comment: Were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that gerrit execs the hook without parsing the command line.

If this happens, you may simply add at the beginning of your script:

```
set $*
```

This will parse the command line again.